# What is better to use, Web service or TCP/IP sockets with Android applications?

Tags: android, web-services, sockets

I am new in mobile development and especially in Android, so I want to know which of the communication types is better TCP/IP sockets or Web Services.
This is for the sake of database accessing.

If the web service is better I need to know if there is a specific type is preferred like RESTful or SOAP.
I'll be so thankful because it will help deciding the future development process for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, and what about a web service types?

Answer (score 1):

you can continue with web-services.there are many types of services. like REST or SOAP or KSOAP. but you need to first take decision that in which platform you need to develop? in .NET or PHP?

Comment: Thanks again. It will be JAVA for android communication with server, I read about those types and I decided to go with RESTful webservices.